# XMLStreamWriter remove prolog

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm writing an xml using XMLStreamWriter. But I do not need the prolog.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

How can I omit this line in my output xml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`XMLStreamWriter` outputs the XML declaration when you call `writeStartDocument()`.

So you can simply skip this call if you don't want to include a XML declaration.